# Smart Mailbox no longer working

Tags: mail.app

The Smart Mailbox I have set up for Wells Fargo emails has stopped populating since January 2016. Previously it had populated properly since I made it in 2010.

I have since received many Wells Fargo Bill Pay emails - but they don't populate into the Smart Mailbox.

I have created another Smart Mailbox with the same name but with a number one (1) after. It shows exactly the same emails.

Comment: Are the criteria you used to create the smart mailbox being met by the new emails coming in since January?  The criteria you select needs to match exactly or the email won't be recognized.

Comment: They're exactly the same as they always were.

Comment: I'm using an iMac with Sierra OS. This happened with previous OS's also.

Answer (score 6):

What fixed it for me was [this procedure](https://www.macissues.com/2015/07/13/fix-mails-smart-mailboxes-not-working-properly/), *i.e.*:

> 1. Go to the Applications > Utilities folder.
> 2. Open Activity Monitor.
> 3. Select “All Processes” from the View menu.
> 4. Search for “mds”.
> 5. Select and quit each instance of “mds” and/or “mdserver” separately (force-quit if you have to).

I had only one instance of “mds”. Force-quitting it was enough to instantly solve the problem. Kudos to MacIssues!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing with an unread mail smart mailbox.  I found the solution was to check in system preferences under spotlight.  go to the privacy tab and check you dont have your HDD tagged.  Dont know how it became tagged but removing it meant that once the Mac had completed the indexing my smart mailbox started working again.